# FileStream in c# - Detection of Stream Position Changes?

Tags: c#, filestream

while i am learning FileStream that is class in system.io [FileStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netcore-3.0#detection-of-stream-position-changes)

I saw a paragraph entitled "Detection of Stream Position Changes" (emphasis mine):

> When a FileStream object does not have an exclusive hold on its handle, another thread could access the file handle concurrently and change the position of the operating system's file pointer that is associated with the file handle. In this case, the cached position in the FileStream object and the cached data in the buffer could be compromised. The FileStream object routinely performs checks on methods that access the cached buffer to ensure that the operating system's handle position is the same as the cached position used by the FileStream object.
>
> **If an unexpected change in the handle position is detected in a call to the Read method, the .NET Framework discards the contents of the buffer and reads the stream from the file again. This can affect performance, depending on the size of the file and any other processes that could affect the position of the file stream.**
>
> If an unexpected change in the handle position is detected in a call to the Write method, the contents of the buffer are discarded and an IOException exception is thrown.

i tried to make this code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        
        Task t1 =Task.Run(() => change());
        Task<string> t = Task.Run(() => mama());
        Thread.Sleep(1);

        textBox1.Text = t.Result;
    }
    void change()
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, 4096, true);
        while(true)
        {
            fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            
        }
    }
    string mama()
    {
        FileStream fs2 = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, 1, true);

        byte[] data = new byte[fs2.Length];
        fs2.Read(data,0, data.Length);
        return Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
    }
```

I expected that no text will append in text box because fs2.read() will discard buffer every time

because fs.seek(0,seekorigin.begin) , but the text append in textbox , why ?

can any one tell me why text append in textbox although i set buffer = 1 and the text is not small

Comment: @John 
ohh , you dont understand me broo 
i know what you say , i mean that paragraph say that Read method discard data in buffer and read again from file when position change by another process ( the first FileStream )

Comment: You might want to include the paragraph prior so that it's clear what your question is about, to be honest. I'm still not 100% clear how that would equate to not being able to read at all, however.

Comment: here i think the read method in second file stream will not finish because first filestream change position every time therefore read method will discard data and re read from file every time and will not return value

Comment: My first guess is that `FileStream` either a) doesn't actually do the seek until you call `Read` or `Write` (not sure), or b) Doesn't seek because it already knows it's at 0 because reading `fs2` won't advance `Position` in `fs`. Second guess is that the OS gives each a little bit of time to fairly distribute access to the file. These are all guesses though.

Comment: Ok  , i will search again in internet and if i find the correct answer i will replay here to you , whatever thanks to you very much for your caring